# nil :selected value for date helper in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm using the following code for a date field:

```
    <%= f.input :date_of_birth, :selected => nil,
                            :order => [:day, :month, :year], 
                            :prompt => {:day => "Day", :month => "Month", :year => "Year"},
                            :start_year => Time.now.year - 15,
                            :end_year => Time.now.year - 100 %>
```

Everything works as expected, except for :selected => nil. I'm using 0.9.7, all the specs pass, including the one regarding a nil :selected value. When I use this though, the current date is selected, save for the year, which doesn't exist.

Am I missing something here? I tried with :as => :date and that did't make any difference.

Tom

Answer (score 4):

This is a known regression/bug in Formtastic right now.  Expect a fix in the next gem release.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to add `:include_blank => true`, maybe that helps?